# Why is this matrix initializing as 2x4 instead of 2x2?

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to create a function that will return a submatrix from a larger matrix. The function is

```
double **getSubmatrix(double **matrix, int n, int m, int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2){
int i, j, subrow, subcol;
subrow = 0;
subcol = 0;
int numSubRows = row2 - row1 + 1;
int numSubCols = col2 - col1 + 1;

// Create Submatrix with indicated size
double **subMatrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * numSubRows);
for (i = 0; i < numSubRows; i++) {
    subMatrix[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * numSubCols);
}
// Add values from matrix into subMatrix
for (i = row1; i <= row2; i++) {
    for (j = col1; j <= col2; j++) {
        subMatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[i][j];
        subcol += 1;
    }
    subrow += 1;
}
return subMatrix;
```

}

The call to the function is

```
mat2 = getSubmatrix(mat1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3)
```

And mat1 is a 3x4 matrix with values

```
8  2  4  1
10 4  2  3
12 42 1  0
```

I'm expecting subMatrix to return a matrix of

```
2  3
1  0
```

But I'm only getting

```
2  3
0  0
```

Because SubMatrix becomes

```
2  3  0  0
0  0  1  0
```

And seg faults as well, even though numSubRows and numSubCols are both 2. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = row1; i <= row2; i++) {
    for (j = col1; j <= col2; j++) {
        subMatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[i][j];
        subcol += 1;
    }
    subrow += 1;
}
```

In that loop above, you fail to set `subcol` back to zero when incrementing `subrow`. That's why you're seeing the cascading effect (untouched cells marked as `.` to make it more obvious):

```
2 3 . .
. . 1 0
```

instead of:

```
2 3
1 0
```

The code, should you wish to make the minimal necessary change, *should* be:

```
for (i = row1; i <= row2; i++) {
    for (j = col1; j <= col2; j++) {
        subMatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[i][j];
        subcol += 1;
    }
    subrow += 1;
    subcol = 0;  // added this line.
}
```

---

However, it may actually be better ditching those `subXXX` variables altogether since you're using a *fixed* base in both dimensions:

```
for (i = row1; i <= row2; i++)
    for (j = col1; j <= col2; j++)
        subMatrix[i-row1][j-col1] = matrix[i][j];
```

---

Two other things I'd like to mention as an aside. First, you should generally *always* check the return value from `malloc()` even if you only use that to exit with an error message. That's far more acceptable than carrying on with undefined behaviour that will be much harder to debug.

And, in C, you shouldn't cast the return value from `malloc()`. C is quite capable of implicitly casting the `void *` return value to any other pointer type and explicitly casting can hide certain subtle errors.

---

For a more robust variant, see the following. It does a lot more sanity checking up front to ensure you're not doing something "strange". It also detects problems with allocating memory and cleans up after itself if necessary.

And it has an extra feature of auto-magically populating variables (if you provide them) with the height and width of the sub-matrix. If you provide `NULL` instead of pointers, it won't worry about it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double **getSubmatrix (
    double **matrix,
    int height, int width,
    int row1, int row2,
    int col1, int col2,
    int *pHeight, int *pWidth
) {
    // Check parameters for validity up front.

    if ((row1 < 0) || (row1 >= height))
        return NULL;
    if ((row2 < 0) || (row2 >= height))
        return NULL;
    if (row2 < row1)
        return NULL;

    if ((col1 < 0) || (col1 >= width))
        return NULL;
    if ((col2 < 0) || (col2 >= width))
        return NULL;
    if (col2 < col1)
        return NULL;

    // Allocate first level, return NULL if no good.

    double **subMatrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * (row2 - row1 + 1));
    if (subMatrix == NULL) return NULL;

    // Allocate second level. If any fail, free all previous.

    for (int row = row1; row <= row2; row++) {
        subMatrix[row - row1] = malloc (sizeof(double) * (col2 - col1 + 1));
        if (subMatrix[row - row1] == NULL) {
            for (int rowfree = 0; rowfree < row; rowfree++) {
                free (subMatrix[rowfree]);
            }
            free (subMatrix);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Now have fully allocated sub-matrix, give size if desired.

    if (pHeight != NULL)
        *pHeight = row2 - row1 + 1;

    if (pWidth != NULL)
        *pWidth = col2 - col1 + 1;

    // Transfer the sub-matrix data and return it.

    for (int row = row1; row <= row2; row++)
        for (int col = col1; col <= col2; col++)
            subMatrix[row - row1][col - col1] = matrix[row][col];

    return subMatrix;
}
```

You can see it in action with the following test harness.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    double **ipp = malloc (sizeof (double *) * 3);

    ipp[0] = malloc (sizeof (double) * 4);
    ipp[1] = malloc (sizeof (double) * 4);
    ipp[2] = malloc (sizeof (double) * 4);

    ipp[0][0] =  8; ipp[0][1] =  2; ipp[0][2] =  4; ipp[0][3] =  1;
    ipp[1][0] = 10; ipp[1][1] =  4; ipp[1][2] =  2; ipp[1][3] =  3;
    ipp[2][0] = 12; ipp[2][1] = 42; ipp[2][2] =  1; ipp[2][3] =  0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            printf ("%5.2f ", ipp[row][col]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');
    int h, w;
    double **part = getSubmatrix (ipp, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, &h, &w);
    if (part == NULL) {
        puts ("Could not get sub-matrix");
    } else {
        for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                printf ("%5.2f ", part[row][col]);
            }
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Darn, just beat me, and with far better formatting =P

Comment: @paxdiablo The code fixed the issue of the values being shifted, but subMatrix still has 4 columns instead of just two. It now shows as `2 3 0 0


1  0 0 0`
I can't make the rows show up on separate lines but I hope you get the idea

Comment: @N0ug4t, that's almost certainly a result of the way you're _printing_ it. The allocated memory itself is of the correct size.

Comment: @paxdiablo You're correct - I was trying to print with variables n & m which were out of the array bounds. Simple oversight on my part. You've been a great help, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors like that, you can increment/initialize `subrow` and `subcol` also in the `for` loops.

```
for (i = row1, subrow = 0; i <= row2; i++, ++subrow) {
   for (j = col1, subcol = 0; j <= col2; j++, ++subcol) {
      subMatrix[subrow][subcol] = matrix[i][j];
   }
}
```